# I want to know how can i see my react project in my mobile using the IP ADDRESS given in the terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, localhost, ip-address

I just started learning `reactjs` and in the tutorial, I saw my teacher showing the react project on his phone, I tried to do the same,

```
  Local:            http://localhost:3001        
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.*.*:****
```

and copied the `On Your Network` IP on my phone but nothing is showing up, moreover, my laptop and phone are connected to the same wifi.

What I am missing here?

Comment: do you know your pc ip address? different pc have different ip. so your teacher's pc has different ip from yours.

Comment: to check your ip on window: to go task manager, go to performance tab/section, go to wifi tab/section, look for IPv4. that is your pc ip. for mac, go to Network in System preferences.

Comment: to test your ip, copy your ip from you need it and replace `localhost` in your browser on your pc and refresh your project page. if your project loaded, you got your ip right.

Comment: I had this problem before. It was my laptop's network connections. I forgot how to fix it though. I remember in windows Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections there were multiple wifi connections. The On Your Network message wasn't showing the correct ip because it was looking at the wrong connection.